# Absolute and conditional convergence of series containing trigonometric functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a slight problem with this kind of exercise. For example, if we have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos{\frac{n\pi}{4}}}{n^a}, a>0$$

Now, for example, say I want to check the absolute convergence of this example. I know that there are negative terms depending on $n$, and the maximum value $\cos{\frac{n\pi}{4}}$ can attain is $1$.

$$\vert\frac{\cos{\frac{n\pi}{4}}}{n^a}\rvert\le \frac{1}{n^a}$$

1. Was I correct to make this deduction?
2. Do I proceed like this any time I have a $sin$ or $cos$ function when checking for absolute convergence?
3. If I am correct, my series absolutely converge for $a>1$. How do we check if it conditionally converges for $0<a<1$?

We are not allowed to use any integration techniques (Abel's and Dirichlet's test are encouraged).

Thanks!

Comment: Actually I originally wrote $1$ but changed it as I was a little bit tired last night and didn't think properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. It's always a good thing to try.
3. You are correct about when it converges absolutely, but keep in mind that so far you haven't shown it *doesn't* converge absolutely for any $a\le 1,$ only that it does converge absolutely for $a>1.$ (Hint: you can lower bound it too, though some terms are zero so it's a little trickier.) The fact that it converges for any $a>0$  follows from one of the two tests you mentioned.

Comment: I tried lower-bounding it by $\frac{-1}{n^a}$  to try to prove divergence by comparison for $a\le1$  but it does not work as the series I am comparing it to diverges $-\infty$. I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: @john You are checking absolute convergence so everything should be positive. You should be proving it is greater than something that diverges to infinity.